# Jenkins Slave unable to connect to master hosted on Openshift instance

Tags: jenkins, openshift

Unable to connect jenkins master hosted On Openshift Cluster. Terminates with below error after handshaking:

```
Apr 03, 2018 4:37:17 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Apr 03, 2018 4:37:17 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 172.30.211.41:30863
Apr 03, 2018 4:37:48 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 172.30.211.41:30863 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 172.30.211.41:30863
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoin
t.java:242)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:671)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:532)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:455)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoin
t.java:203)
        ... 3 more
```

I am connecting windows machine (VM) as a slave. Any suggestions? TIA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used NodePort to connect the slave. And configuring hostname:Port under tunneling option in slave configuration under jenkins. It works!

Answer (score 1):

The instance is not able to connect.

```
INFO: Connecting to 172.30.211.41:30863 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 172.30.211.41:30863
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

The IP address of the Service in openshift, right? This IP is only accessible within the OpenShift cluster. Try to use route if the slave is running outside of the cluster.

Comment: Yes, slave is outside cluster. I have used NodePort to connect the slave. And configuring hostname:Port under tunneling option in slave configuration under jenkins. It works!

Comment: Then I would check the firewall. The error says it time outs. The packet was dropped.